# Is it possible to have the same prompt and profile settings across both Bash and Zsh shells?

Tags: bash, terminal, zsh

I start to get itchy when my code isn't DRY, and for various reasons, I jump back and forth between Bash and Zsh. Instead of copy/pasting between multiple profiles, is there a way to point to a central file, and`source`it in each profile, keeping my prompts, aliases, RVM config and settings together in one file?

Looking at Ryan Bates' dotfiles, it seems like .bashrc is the place to do this. Is this the preferred solution? https://github.com/ryanb/dotfiles/commit/ac7e0c55ce038cbeadd8da2f521eb034d09eb131

Comment: It's been a while since I've used Zsh, but if I recollect correctly, Zsh largely supports Bash and can be though of as a super set. There are a number of ways of unifying the profiles, but one approach would be to make a symbolic link from your Zsh configuration to your Bash. For the inevitable differences that will arise, you can conditionalize where needed.

Comment: They have different syntaxes for prompts and shell options, so those will need to be separate. But you can source a common file for things they both have.

Answer (score 0):

[My dotfiles](https://github.com/haletom/dotfiles) are written to be runnable in both `{ba,z}sh` and have the same behaviour in both shells.

- Prompt setup must be done on a per-shell basis.
- Use `zsh`'s `emulate bash` before `source`ing `bash` files
- [Array indexing requires more verbose syntax to be portable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56310835/5353461)

To determine which shell, you're in, use:

```
if [ -n $BASH_VERSION ]; then
    # Bash specific
else
    # zsh specific
fi
```

Also, see [my common bash and zsh functions](https://github.com/HaleTom/dotfiles/blob/master/bash/.config/bash/functions) for a grab-bag of useful functions which work equivalently in both `bash` and `zsh`.