# Portable array indexing in both bash and zsh

Tags: bash, zsh

Array indexing is `0`-based in `bash`, and `1`-based in `zsh` (unless option `KSH_ARRAYS` is set).

As an example: To access the first element of an array, is there something nicer than:

```
if [ -n $BASH_VERSION ]; then
    echo ${array[0]}
else
    echo ${array[1]}
fi
```

Comment: Wouldn't setting `KSH_ARRAYS` be the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### TL;DR:

To always get consistent behaviour, use:

```
${array[@]:offset:length}
```

---

### Explanation

For code which works in both `bash` and `zsh`, you need to use the `offset:length` syntax rather than the `[subscript]` syntax.

Even for `zsh`-only code, you'll still need to do this (or use `emulate -LR zsh`) since `zsh`'s array subscripting basis is determined by the [option `KSH_ARRAYS`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#Shell-Emulation).

Eg, to reference the first element in an array:

```
${array[@]:0:1}
```

Here, `array[@]` is all the elements, `0` is the offset (which *always* is 0-based), and `1` is the number of elements desired.